# Make SQL Server 2008 Instance invisible (nonpublic)

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2008, privileges

We need to make some instances of our SQL Server invisible, so you can't view it from SQL Server Management Studio "Browse for servers" screen but you can connect to it if you know its instance name...

Also prevent any possibility of getting the list of the other instances from inside an instance that you are connected

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried changing the default TCP port?

Comment: I doubt you can, but why is it an issue anyway? - without any connection permissions, all anyone else will be able to determine is the instance name.

Comment: How fast when i added the anwser there was already 3 anwsers so i will give te points to the first one that matches my own...thanks people!

Comment: The idea is using each instance for a different client who will connect remotely to our servers...so we would like some "privacy" for them (it has to be instances and not databases because software requirements...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for.
[How to: Hide an Instance of SQL Server Database Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179327%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)
[image]

Comment: Can't get this to work. It doesn't just hide the instance but also prevents connections to it even though you have "know" the connectionstring and can type it without browsing. did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned, I'd suggest you use a non-standard TCP port for the "protected" instance and disable the SQL Browser service.  You'd need to then know the server + instance name + port number to connect using SSMS.

I haven't tested this configuration, but off the top of my head I think this will make it tougher for instance detection.

Is there any particular reason for wanting to "hide" the instance?  Can't you just set up login/security account restrictions to prevent unauthorized access?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would be sufficient:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179327.aspx

It is configuration option.

Answer (score 0):

It seems we didnt google about it with the correct keywords...searching about hidding instance returned the answer:

To hide an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine

In SQL Server Configuration Manager, expand SQL Server Network Configuration, right-clickProtocols for , and then selectProperties.

On the Flags tab, in the HideInstance box, select Yes, and then click OK to close the dialog box. The change takes effect immediately for new connections.

Comment: Hides it from the SQL Browser service.. but any idea if it hides the instance from SSMS's browse dialog?  Or does SSMS use a SQL Browser service to locate the other servers/instances?