# How to make an instance of SQL Server hidden (not show up in browsing) via command line

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I know how to hide an instance from being browsed:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179327.aspx also answered here
[Make SQL Server 2008 Instance invisible (nonpublic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309365/make-mssql-2008-instance-invisible-nonpublic)

My question is how do you do this via the commandline?

This comprehensively lists the options when installing SQL Server via a command line: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx - It does not mention the "hidden" property of the instance, so I assume it is not possible to set at this point.

At this point I'm just flicking the DWORD at:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.instancename\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketLib\HideInstance

```
1 = Hidden
0 = Not hidden/browsable
```

Using this `REG` command:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLVERSION\INSTANCENAME\SuperSocketNetLib" /v "HideInstance" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
```

Note: You must check you path and adjust for version and instance name to use this.

**What is the best way to change this post install? Does anyone see a problem with my workaround?**

Comment: This will potentially hide the instance from the most casual observers, but you know it doesn't really make it hidden, right? Except in the case where you can turn off all of the network protocols except shared memory, and only have applications interact with SQL Server local to the box, it will still be discoverable for anyone willing to try more than the Browse... button.

Comment: What is the purpose of "hiding" your database?

Comment: Also note that after applying that registry change I am fairly certain you will also have to restart the SQL Server service (you can do this with `net stop` and `net start`).

Comment: Yes, a stop/start is necessary. I should have mentioned it.

This is to hide from casual observation. We want the instances hidden from users browsing SQL servers from some applications that provide that sort of dialogs. Casual observation would be an good description.

Yes I know the instance is still available through name and IP:port, which is how I want it.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Why not just disable the SQL browser service altogether?

Answer (score 1):

@steoleary That is what I came to too. I thought hiding the instance hid it from browsing, but it makes it hidden from the Server Browser even if you "ask" for it by name. It must have made a mistake testing... As far as I can tell there is not way to not make an instance not being browsable and still addressable by name. It seems if you hide it you need address it by server+port. Thats not going to fly here, so I guess we're not hiding any instances. Thanks for your answers.

Answering my own question since what I was asking wasn't really possible.

TLDR; Hiding an instance will make it invisible to browsing AND unreachable by name (SERVER\INSTANCE). Not what I wanted. Disabling the Server Browser is a better way of hiding all instances.